# Nunit runsTestCase with a TestCaseSource with the first iteration having no parameters? Why?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, testcase, testcasesource

Hi I am new to Nunit and I am passing a series of objects to a TestCase as a TestCaseSource. For some reason though Nunit seems to run the test first with no parameters passed to it which results in an ignored output:

The test:

```
private readonly object[] _nunitIsWeird =
{
    new object[] {new List<string>{"one", "two", "three"}, 3},
    new object[] {new List<string>{"one", "two"}, 2}

};

[TestCase, TestCaseSource("_nunitIsWeird")]
public void TheCountsAreCorrect(List<string> entries, int expectedCount)
{
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedCount,Calculations.countThese(entries));
}
```

> TheCountsAreCorrect (3 tests), Failed: One or more child tests had errors
>           TheCountsAreCorrect(), Ignored: No arguments were provided
>           TheCountsAreCorrect(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String],2), Success
>           TheCountsAreCorrect(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String],3), Success

So the first test is ignored because there are no parameters, but I don't want this test run, ever, it makes no sense and it's mucking up my test output. I tried ignoring it and that sets the test output correctly but it comes back when I run all tests again.

Is there something I am missing, I have looked everywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`TestCase` and `TestCaseSource` do two different things.  You just need to remove the `TestCase` attribute.

```
[TestCaseSource("_nunitIsWeird")]
public void TheCountsAreCorrect(List<string> entries, int expectedCount)
{
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedCount,Calculations.countThese(entries));
}
```

The [TestCase](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCase&r=2.5) attribute is for supplying inline data, so NUnit is attempting to supply no parameters to the test, which is failing.  Then it's processing the [TestCaseSource](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.5.9) attribute, and looking up the data that it supplies and trying to pass that to the test as well, which is working correctly.

As a side note, strictly speaking, the docs suggest that you should also mark your `TestCaseSource` test with a `Test` attribute like below, however I've never found this necessary:

```
[Test, TestCaseSource("_nunitIsWeird")]
public void TheCountsAreCorrect(List<string> entries, int expectedCount)
```

Comment: Thanks forsvarir, it was my misreading of the text which meant that I was using TastCase instead of Test . Thank you